# Can I pre-compute a variable and then use it later in a razor HTML script?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have my HTML / razor code that looks like this:

```
@model Content.Grid
<tr id="row_@(Model.Row)" 
    data-pk="@(Model.PartitionKey)"
    data-rk="@(Model.RowKey)">
   <td>
@(Model.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0')).@(Model.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0'))
  </td>
   <td>
@(Model.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0')).@(Model.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0'))
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is just an example but in my application I have columns that repeat the same computation a few times. Is there a way that I could do this at the start of the 
code and then just use the value in each column. Something like pre-computing this and then just placing the Obj local variable inside my ?

```
@{
    Obj = Model.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0'))
}
```

I tried this but can't seem to get this to work.

Please note. I cannot change the Model in my application. The computation has to be inside the razor file.

Comment: Can I ask why you can't change the Model?  Perhaps you could use a ViewModel one of whose properties is the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why not.  Give this a try:

```
@model Content.Grid

@{
    var result = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Model.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0'), Model.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0'));
}

<tr id="row_@(Model.Row)" 
    data-pk="@(Model.PartitionKey)"
    data-rk="@(Model.RowKey)">
    <td>
        @result
    </td>
    <td>
        @result
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems what I was doing wrong was missing the word "var" :-(